# Extract specific XMLs from log file

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, xmlstarlet

I have large log files (around 50mb each), which contain java debug information plus all kinds of XML responses

Here's an example of something I'm trying to extract from the log

```
<envelope>
    <response>
        <ATTR name="uniqueid" value="XYZ_00000-00-00_12345_1"/>
        <ATTR name="status" value="Activated"/>
        <ATTR name="datecreated" value="2018/10/04 09:39:05"/>
    </response>
</envelope>
```

I need only the XMLs which the uniqueid attribute **contains** "12345" and the status attribute is set to "Activated"

By using "sed" I'm able to extract all the envelopes, and currently I'm using regex to check if the above conditions exist inside of it (by running all of them in a loop).

```
sed -n '/<envelope>/,/<\/envelope>/p' logfile
```

What would be a proper solution to extract what I need from the file?

Thanks!

Comment: Whoever generated that XML clearly has no idea how to best use XML.

Comment: You should be using an XML parser to parse XML data. What else is in this log file? Show some more of it.

Comment: @glennjackman most of it is not XML but all sorts of java logs (debug/info/errors).

Comment: someone reinvented attribute as a tag, but still needed name/value attributes?

Comment: Can we focus on the question in hand though? I did not generate those XMLs so I cannot answer for the quality of its structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your xml is formatted as shown, this should work...

```
$ awk '/<envelope>/ {line=$0; p=0; next} 
             line   {line=line ORS $0} 
    /uniqueid/ && $3~/12345/ {p=1}
   /<\/envelope>/ && p {print line}' file
```

with the opening tag, start accumulating the lines, if the desired line found set the flag, with the end tag if the flag is set print the record.

with `gawk` you can do this instead

```
$ awk -F'\n' -v RS='</envelope>\n'    \
    '$3~/uniqueid.*12345/ && $4~/status.*Activated/{print $0, RT}' file
```

there will be an extra newline though.

Comment: Thank you! This works great! Could you please also include the 'status' attribute as 'Activated' to this pattern?

Comment: status activated